# как менять расположение QSplliter -a на Widget - е?

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь выставить  Splliter на 1/3 часть фрейма но не выходит:

```
      ui->splitter->resize(r_frame.width()*0.20); //ошибка
      ui->splitter->setOrientation(f_frame*0.20); //ошибка
```

При запуске программы получаю вот такую картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотел бы получить такую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция

```
void QSplitter::setSizes(const QList<int> &list)
```

Согласно документации:

> Sets the child widgets' respective sizes to the values given in the list.
>   If the splitter is horizontal, the values set the width of each widget in pixels, from left to right. If the splitter is vertical, the height of each widget is set, from top to bottom.

Пример использования в моей программе:

```
ui->splitter->setSizes(QList <int> () << 250 << 350);
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало :3